# Insert Your Windows Installation Disc

Tags: 8.0, htc-8x

My HTC 8X doesn't boot and shows a black screen with this message "Insert Your Windows Installation Disc".

How do I get out of this? Where do I get such a disk? Where do I insert it?

**Edit**:

I wasn't doing anything with the phone, the phone seems to have crashed / shutdown when it was on a charger overnight.

**Edit 2**

No, I don't have an "app that fakes this screen" (!).

Comment: http://winsupersite.com/windows-phone/calling-bs-windows-phone-8-handset-asks-installation-disc

Comment: Would love to see a pic.

Comment: Why all the downvotes? Because a renowned Windows fanboy says this is not possible?

Comment: It might be a good idea to take a screenshot with a digital camera. This would help invalidate that other site's claims.

Comment: @user990778 Downvotes are normally done when a question is unclear or shows little research - you've not included any information on what you where doing before this happened, nor included a photo that demonstrates it.

Comment: As nobody here believes this can really happen when you "wasn't doing anything with the phone", there would be no constructive answer. Did you really mean your questions "Where do I get such a disk? Where do I insert it?" seriously? I don't think so. I don't believe your question is serious at all.

Answer (score 4):

This error occurs only under two circumstances:

1. Attempting to flash the memory. Especially when done by inexpirienced user.
2. Using one of the apps or websites that fake error screen.

Cure for first one is simple, but expensive: go to service and ask them to fix the phone, or swap it for a new one.

Cure for second one is even simpler and free: hold windows and <- key till the screen with apps selection pops up - pick your desktop. Or just press the search button ;)

Comment: I didn't do anything of that sort. How can you say the error ONLY occurs under that condition?

Comment: I'm a developer, seen a lot of things. And got quite deep knowledge how this error can be triggered. Only messing with memory by the user can make it happen, but in 99% of cases it's just people using apps on WP to make a laugh of it. I seen scams like that many, many times, and I also seen people insisting that they didn't do anything and "error popped all by itself".

Comment: Pray share your deep knowledge. I'm a developer too and am intrigued by your claim that this error can be triggered in ONE WAY ONLY. Unless I was directly involved in developing the bootloader in this case, I would never make that claim!

Comment: @user990778 we are also intrigued by your claim about that screen. I see here that you believe in MarcinWolny knowledge as much as we believe your story... Try to convince us with something more then your words.

Answer (score 4):

Currently Windows 8 phones should still be under warranty. Exchange it for a new one with your provider.